# Mismatch in WETH shown in Metamask wallet and shown by code

Tags: metamask, wrapped-tokens, etherjs

[image]

tokenContractAddress is 0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab
on execution, returns

[image]

but balance of WETH in my wallet is 2 WETH as i can see.
How is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are checking balance of contract in code , whereas in metamask , you are chcking balance of weth in the user address.

Comment: Got it right...

Comment: How can I check WETH balance of user using etherjs?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thank you @Ashish.
We need to use address of wallet instead of contract address